# Add correlated subqueries to Select statement using QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm attempting to convert a SQL statement to use QueryOver (in hopes of pre-fetching the entities part of the response) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add a correlated subquery to the Select statement (all the examples I found have only shown using a subquery in the Where clause).

This is the query I'm trying to convert:

```
var pendingFeedbackStatus = Session.QueryOver<FeedbackStatus>().Where(fs => fs.Name == "pending");
var projectWhereClause = project != null ? "AND f1.project_id = " + project.Id : "";

var query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(string.Format(@"
        SELECT
            ft.id as FEEDBACK_TYPE_ID,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FEEDBACK f1 WHERE ft.id = f1.feedback_type_id AND f1.archive_ind = 0 {0}) as ALL_FEEDBACK_COUNT,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FEEDBACK f1 WHERE ft.id = f1.feedback_type_id AND f1.archive_ind = 0 {0} AND feedback_status_id = {1}) as PENDING_FEEDBACK_COUNT
        FROM feedback f
        RIGHT JOIN feedback_type ft on f.feedback_type_id = ft.id WHERE ft.RESTRICTED_IND = 0
        GROUP BY ft.id, ft.sort_order
        ORDER BY ft.sort_order",
        projectWhereClause,
        pendingFeedbackStatus.Id
    ))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap);

var results =  query.List<IDictionary>();
return results.Select(r =>
    new FeedbackTypeSummary
    {
        Type = Get(Convert.ToInt32(r["FEEDBACK_TYPE_ID"])),
        AllFeedbackCount = Convert.ToInt32(r["ALL_FEEDBACK_COUNT"]),
        PendingFeedbackCount = Convert.ToInt32(r["PENDING_FEEDBACK_COUNT"])
    }).ToList();
```

and here is what I have so far (which is mostly everything minus the correlated subqueries and some additional filtering added to the subqueries):

```
var pendingFeedbackStatus = Session.QueryOver<FeedbackStatus>().Where(fs => fs.Name == "pending");

Feedback feedbackAlias = null;
FeedbackType feedbackTypeAlias = null;

var allFeedback = QueryOver.Of<Feedback>()
    .Where(f => f.Type.Id == feedbackTypeAlias.Id)
    .Where(f => !f.IsArchived);

var pendingFeedback = QueryOver.Of<Feedback>()
    .Where(f => f.Type.Id == feedbackTypeAlias.Id)
    .Where(f => !f.IsArchived)
    .Where(f => f.Status.Id == pendingFeedbackStatus.Id);

var foo = Session.QueryOver<Feedback>(() => feedbackAlias)
    .Right.JoinAlias(f => f.Type, () => feedbackTypeAlias, ft => !ft.IsRestricted)
    .SelectList(list => list
        // TODO: Add correlated subqueries here?
        .SelectGroup(() => feedbackTypeAlias.Id)
        .SelectGroup(() => feedbackTypeAlias.SortOrder)
     )
    .OrderBy(() => feedbackTypeAlias.SortOrder).Asc;

var test = foo.List<object[]>();
```

I'd also like to find a way to return a full `FeedbackType` entity of from the statement, instead of returning feedbackTypeAlias.Id and then having to perform `Type = Get(Convert.ToInt32(r["FEEDBACK_TYPE_ID"]))` in a loop as I do in the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I felt like I looked for this 10 times, but I overlooked the `.SelectSubQuery()` method which provided the desired correlated subqueries.  This answer tipped me off - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8143684/191902.

Here is the full QueryOvery version:

```
var pendingFeedbackStatus = Session.QueryOver<FeedbackStatus>().Where(fs => fs.Name == "pending").SingleOrDefault();

Domain.Feedback.Feedback feedbackAlias = null;
FeedbackType feedbackTypeAlias = null;
var allFeedback = QueryOver.Of<Domain.Feedback.Feedback>()
    .Where(f => f.Type.Id == feedbackTypeAlias.Id)
    .Where(f => !f.IsArchived);

var pendingFeedback = QueryOver.Of<Domain.Feedback.Feedback>()
    .Where(f => f.Type.Id == feedbackTypeAlias.Id)
    .Where(f => !f.IsArchived)
    .Where(f => f.Status.Id == pendingFeedbackStatus.Id);

if (project != null)
{
    allFeedback.Where(f => f.Project.Id == project.Id);
    pendingFeedback.Where(f => f.Project.Id == project.Id);
}

FeedbackTypeSummary result = null;
var query = Session.QueryOver<Domain.Feedback.Feedback>(() => feedbackAlias)
    .Right.JoinAlias(f => f.Type, () => feedbackTypeAlias, ft => !ft.IsRestricted)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectSubQuery(allFeedback.ToRowCountQuery()).WithAlias(() => result.AllFeedbackCount)
        .SelectSubQuery(pendingFeedback.ToRowCountQuery()).WithAlias(() => result.PendingFeedbackCount)
        .SelectGroup(() => feedbackTypeAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => result.TypeId)
        .SelectGroup(() => feedbackTypeAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => result.TypeName)
        .SelectGroup(() => feedbackTypeAlias.NamePlural).WithAlias(() => result.TypeNamePlural)
        .SelectGroup(() => feedbackTypeAlias.SortOrder)
    )
    .OrderBy(() => feedbackTypeAlias.SortOrder).Asc
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<FeedbackTypeSummary>());

var results = query.List<FeedbackTypeSummary>();
return results;
```

I also was able to populate my `FeedbackTypeSummary` DTO from a single query, although I couldn't find a way to alias an entity and ended up extracting a few of the needed properties from `FeedbackType` into `FeedackTypeSummary` (which is probably a better thing to do anyways).